# Relation in a repeater, display relation attributes

Tags: octobercms

Thanks to the builder plugin and some small PHP code, I could setup a relation in a repeater.

Basically, I created a recipe system (the repeater is used for multiple recipes) and each repeater have a title, a price, a category.

The category field is a relation with a recipe category model.

Now, I'm trying to display the category title on frontend for each recipe. Here is my code (the loaded object is my menu that contain recipes in the repeater)

```
{% set records = builderList.records %}
{% for record in records %}
  <article class="record">
      <h3>{{ record.title }}</h3>
      <p class="price">{{ record.price }}</p>
      {% for recipes in record.recipes %}
        {{ recipes.category }}
      {% endfor %}
  </article>    
{% endfor %}
```

This code works, but it display the ID of the category (1, 2, 3, etc....) How can I display the title. I tried {{ recipes.category.title }} but it doesn't work. I think I miss a twig syntax to load the relation object to be able to display sub-attributes, but I'm new to laravel and october cms...

Thank you for your help

Comment: what version of laravel?

Comment: I believe october CMS is actually on Laravel 5.1

Comment: Still need an answer to this, I'm stuck at displaying the category title instead of the ID